# Задание: переместить нулевые ячейки в массиве строк в конец, а заполненные - в начало. Использовать только один цикл for и while

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

```
public class Movement {
public static String[] compress(String[] array) {
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
String cell = array[index];
if (cell == null) {
// переместить cell
// Здесь нужен цикл while
}
System.out.print(array[index] + " ");
}
return array;
}
```

Comment: А что, Arrays.sort() кто-то отменял? зачем вообще циклы?

Comment: Как вариант - добавить всё в `List` и отфильтровать `null` значения из него.

Comment: Нужно использовать только то, что в условии задания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String[] compress(String[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String cell = array[i];
        if (cell == null) {
            int j = i + 1;
            while(j < array.length && array[j] == null)
                j++;
            if(j < array.length){
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!